# Why is nautilus trying to connect to the internet?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

When I'm opening nautilus via the gnome-terminal, using `nautilus &`, I get the following messages.

```
** (nautilus:29419): WARNING **: 16:51:41.696: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

(nautilus:29419): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:51:42.332: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(nautilus:29419): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:51:42.332: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(nautilus:29419): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:51:42.332: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

To me this seems like nautilus is trying to connect to the internet.

Any idea why this is happening.

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.30.1.

## update

After manually killing nautilus using `sudo kill PID`, still the error messages shows up,

```
** (nautilus:2454): WARNING **: 17:41:57.107: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

(nautilus:2454): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 17:41:57.840: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(nautilus:2454): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:41:57.840: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(nautilus:2454): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:41:57.840: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addition to the existing answer, you should be aware that what `nautilus` error mentions is [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus). At the lower level, it's basically a way of communication between processes and surprise - you need to have a connection to that communication method. So nautilus is making a connection, just not to the internet but to sort of small, internal system network

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not trying to connect to the internet.

The messages appear because `nautilus` process was already running.
To see a list of running processes you can run the command `ps -A`.
To see a list of processes by name of nautilus you can run the command `ps aux | grep nautilus`.

You can manually kill all the `nautilus` processes using `sudo kill PID` and then if you type `nautilus &`, the messages won't appear.

The `connection` you see here does not refer to the Internet connection rather it is related to Inter-process communication(IPC) mechanism between processes of your machine. This is the Wikepedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) that gives some background about D-bus in general while this [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GDBusConnection.html) here will take you to the GIO reference manual of GDBus connection. The manual provides all the information about the messages you have included in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just updated the question. Can you please tell me, what is `17:41:57.107`. To me this seems like an IP address :)

Comment: @Aparna This is simply time in 24 hrs format. It must be 17 hours, 41 minutes, 57.107 seconds in your region. Try executing command again and compare side by side with current time of the OS just to be sure. :)

Comment: @Kulfy Oh really! thank you very much for clearing that up :)

Comment: @NPsoft any tips/guidance to educate my self with these topics :)

Comment: Check this link for learning how to [manually kill processes](https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/forcefully-close-a-program-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: @Aparna Just to add up whenever a new process arrives it is assigned a Process ID or PID so it can be identified uniquely. You can learn more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). And the number beside nautilus which 2454 is its Process id.