# G_IS_DBUS_connection failed

Tags: putty

I am new to Linux, trying to connect to Nucleo board using putty. I am sure the serial line is correct, this is the message error I got in terminal:

```
(putty:10263): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:18:45.537: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(putty:10263): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:18:45.537: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(putty:10263): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:18:45.537: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(putty:10263): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:18:45.537: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(putty:10263): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:18:45.537: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104648). Basically, whatever process you're running is already running. Use `ps -A` or `ps aux` to see what processes are running (if you have a lot of processes running, you can try `grep`ing the output to find what you're looking for). Kill it with `sudo kill PID` and the errors should stop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `fcitx-module-dbus`:

```
sudo apt-get purge fcitx-module-dbus
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion "sudo apt-get purge fcitx-module-dbus" above solved it for me on ubuntu 18.04.3.

According to wiki, Fcitx is an X extension for asian language keyboard input, so no loss of functionality for me.

"an input method framework with extension support for the X Window System that supports multiple input method engines including Pinyin transcription, table-based input methods (e.g. Wubi method), fcitx-chewing for Traditional Chinese, fcitx-keyboard for layout-based ones, fcitx-mozc for Japanese, fcitx-hangul for Korean."